# How to create maui splash screen with starting codebehind?

Tags: android, maui

I'm confused with how .NET MAUI is setup to create a custom splash screen with activity that runs while it is displaying.

It looks like in the project file you just have:

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />
```

By default. Is there anywhere the user can see when this is actually displayed, and add some more starting activity tasks that are performed before the main activity is displayed - appshell in my case.

in the App where I am running I have:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

So am not seeing where MauiSplashScreen is running - it's obviously displaying with a delay somewhere, but don't know if it's user accessible. If not, it seems like it's very limiting in allowing the user to customize the splashScreen, only allowing the user to being able to change the picture and nothing else. Is this correct?

Thanks,

Comment: the splashscreen is designed to show the user something while the app is initializing.  If you need to do additional setup, do it after the app starts

Comment: It also can be used to show the user stuff while you are doing crap - at least in normal .net framework. I've done it before in wpf. I don't know why this ability would have to be removed in .net maui.

Comment: iOS and Android place strict restrictions on how long the app can spend in startup, so it is best not to place additional code in the startup process